# Copying dates from a row and inserting conditionally by increasing the dates?

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I have got thress columns

```
    A            B          C
12/16/2011  12/17/2011  12/19/2011
1/16/2012   1/17/2012   1/19/2012
2/16/2012               2/19/2012
3/16/2012   3/23/2012
```

Now I have two conditions :

```
1) Date in column B > Date in column A

   Date in column C > Date in column B
```

Also the diference between the dates between A and B, B and C  should not be more than 3 days.

```
2) any row in B or C should not be empty .
```

if the above conditions are not met for a row, then update B or C accordingly.

```
i.e set Date of B= (Date of A) + 1
 set Date of C=(Date of B) + 1
```

**NOTE : A is source column**

Comment: OK, so that's what you have to do.  What is your question?

Comment: I need to update columns B and C if conditions 1) and 2) are not met such that date in B is greater that A by 1 and Date in C is greater than B by 1

Comment: Yes I know what you have to do.  I don't know what you are asking though. You need to write an UPDATE statement.

Comment: :) yes you are right, I am a complete newbie at this...just wodering how do i copy values from the cells in A and put it in others by incrementing the dates by and i need to check the conditions also ...:-)

Comment: actually it's not such a simple question, does it have to be one update ? if so, then changing b to a+1 may cause that c is now not greater than the new b ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I'd do it with 2 updates (I'm assuming the type of A,B and C is DATE),
**first:**

```
update <<your_table>>
set b = a + 1
where nvl(b, to_date('00010101','yyyymmdd')) <= a
```

**second:**

```
update <<your_table>>
set c = b + 1
where nvl(c, to_date('00010101','yyyymmdd')) <= b
```

the NVL is for the empty cells - I'm givving them a very low value so they will match the condition